# A countable set has outer measure zero. Explanation of Royden example.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

This is an example from Royden's Real Analysis 4th edition that I am having a lot of trouble understanding.

A countable set has outer measure zero.  Let $C$ be a countable set enumerated as $C=\{c_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  For each natural number $k$, define $I_k=(c_k-\epsilon/2^{k+1}, c_k+\epsilon/2^{k+1})$.  The countable collection of open intervals $\{I_k\}_{\infty}^{k=1}$ covers $C$.  Therefore:

$$ 0 \leq m^*(C)\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \ell(I_k)=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\epsilon/2^k = \epsilon$$

This inequality holds for each $\epsilon > 0$.  Hence $m^*(E) = 0$.

What I understand along with questions:

- A countable set is a set like the natural numbers.
- $C=\{c_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is just a way to describe said countable set using indexing for all of the elements in the set.
- $I_k=(c_k-\epsilon/2^{k+1}, c_k+\epsilon/2^{k+1})$ I kind of understand.  This is defining an open cover over the countable set (I think).
- Why the $\epsilon/2^{k+1}$ instead of just $\epsilon$? It looks like the interval is continually shrinking as n goes to infinity.
- The equation in the middle is summing up all of the intervals.  The outer measure is simply the sum of all of the open intervals in the set C.  $m^*(C)$ is countably subadditive, hence the $\leq$ sign here:  $m^*(C)\leq \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \ell(I_k)$
- How is the last summation producing epsilon?
- How is this summing to zero?

Thank you for your help.

-Idle

Comment: Why $\epsilon /2^{k+1}$ rather than $\epsilon$? $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\epsilon$ diverges, which isn't very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

6) $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k}}=\epsilon\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{k}}=\epsilon\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{1-\dfrac{1}{2}}=\epsilon$.

7) No, the sum is $\epsilon$, but now we have $0\leq m^{\ast}(C)<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, if $m^{\ast}(C)>0$, then put $\epsilon$ to be $m^{\ast}(C)$, then we arrive to $m^{\ast}(C)<m^{\ast}(C)$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you.  Any advice for how to get better at this?  I study hard but this is even more difficult, conceptually, than real analysis.

Comment: Maybe you can consult to a more elementary book to build up the foundation, I would suggest that, *Theory of Measure and Integration*, J Yeh, this book actually does not seem to be easier, but at least, the author writes out every detail of the argument, which leads the reader for easy reading.

Comment: I should have said "classical real analysis" in my last comment.  Of course, measure theory / lebesgue integration is real analysis just at a higher level.

Comment: Okay, then try *A First Course in Mathematical Analysis*, David Alexander Brannan, this book builds up the essential feeling of mathematical analysis at its best.